# Change the wording of the character-limit error from "X characters too much" to "X characters too many" on the Chat.SE profile

Tags: feature-request, chat, wording, character-limit, chat-profile

On my chat.SE profile, I entered a few characters too many and saw this error:

[image: current error: "2 chars too much"]

Can we change that to "X characters too many", or "Too long by X characters" to be consistent with the comment errors, and also because we don't want... "too much characters"?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker but "X chars too many" sounds odd to me. I've seen "X too many" but never "X sth too many". I could be wrong though. In any case, "Too long by X characters" sounds better and, as you said, is consistent with comment errors, so I think it's the better option. On another note, I have no idea why your post is receiving downvotes. It seems a pretty fair request to me.

Comment: Yes, this should be changed. "Much" is if the quantity is indeterminate (e.g. decimal numbers), whereas for discrete quantities (integers), it should be "many".

Comment: There are [a lot on English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=many%20%20much) (though with a lot of false positives), but it is not easy to find the canonical question. Candidate: *[“As much details as you can remember”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/204791)*

Comment: I’m a native speaker, and “2 characters too many” sounds completely normal to me, and I’ve definitely seen that construction before. On the other hand, “2 characters too much” doesn’t sound quite right.